# Hive: Invoking shell commands from hive-script throws error

Tags: shell, hive, sh

I have a hive script that executes some DMLs and drop some tables, and executes some shell-delete files. I am firing the script using `hive -f myscript.hql`.
From within the script I need to remove files from local directory. I tried to use `!rm /home/myuser/temp_table_id_*;` throws error:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/myuser/temp_table_id_*’: No such file or directory
Command failed with exit code = 1
```

`*` is not working.
Here is a sample script:

```
--My HQL File--
INSERT OVERWRITE ....
...
..;
DROP TABLE TEMP_TABLE;
!hadoop fs -rm -r /user/myuser/ext_tables/temp_table;
!rm /home/myuser/temp_table_id_*;

CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE(
....
...
;
```

I am calling the script with the command: `hive -f myscript.hql`
The script is running fine till it finds the line :`!rm /home/myuser/temp_table_id_*;` where is cursing about the `*`.
When I am providing separate file names instead of the `*`, its working.
But i wish to use `*`.

Comment: where are you invoking the script from?

Comment: i am using `hive -f filename.hql`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dfs -rm /home/myuser/temp_table_id_*;
```

in the HQL. Wildcard works well with hive dfs commands.

From [Hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli)

```
dfs <dfs command> -Executes a dfs command from the Hive shell.
```